# SQL Expression missing error

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I am trying to select from a table with the average of columns from other tables from other tables; The schema is as follows.

**Students** (`sid`, `firstname`, l`astname`, `status`, `gpa`, `email`)

**Enrollments** (`sid`, `classid`, `lgrade`)

**Grades** (`lgrade`, `ngrade`)

And the erroneous query is,

```
select sid, lastname, 
avg( select g.ngrade from grades g, enrollments e 
    where e.sid = sid and g.lgrade = e.lgrade and e.lgrade is not null 
    and g.ngrade is not null) as cgpa
from students
order by cgpa asc;
```

Comment: The error I am getting is EXPRESION MISSING...on line 2

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to put the average *inside* the subquery? `select sid, lastname, (select avg(g.ngrade) from ...) ...)`

Comment: Will that give me average of all of the values in that column or the result would be many tuples with a column? I am unable to imagine here.

Comment: Yes, that worked , but with the wrong results, which means the problem is with the where clause. I'll check that! Thanks!

Comment: Consider putting the subquery in the `from` clause grouping by `sid` and joining with `students`

Comment: Please describe what average you want to calculate.

Answer (score 1):

Take the semi-colon out of your subquery.

Comment: The error is still there without semicolon,
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00936: missing expression

Comment: the semi-colon has been removed from the post.

Answer (score 1):

There are several issues:

- Remove the semicolon from the subquery.
- You're attempting to use a correlated subquery as a value expression. That's fine, but you have to wrap it in parentheses to do so. I only see one set of parentheses, the ones for the `avg()` function.
- You're also missing an alias on a column. For clarity in expressing your intent, you should be consistent and use aliases throughout.
- Last, a `GROUP BY` clause is required somewhere.

All in all, I think the aggregate should be inside the parentheses.

Try:

```
select
   sid,
   lastname, 
   (
      select avg(g.ngrade)
      from grades g, enrollments e 
      where e.sid = sid and g.lgrade = e.lgrade
      and g.ngrade is not null
   ) as cgpa
from students
order by cgpa asc;
```

Other notes: `e.lgrade is not null` is not needed since the condition `g.lgrade = e.lgrade` already ensures it won't be null.

Last, I encourage you to learn ANSI join syntax. You'll thank me later. Seriously, using old-style joins is awful.

```
select
   s.sid,
   s.lastname, 
   (
      select avg(g.ngrade)
      from
         grades g
         inner join enrollments e
            on g.lgrade = e.lgrade
      where
         g.ngrade is not null
         and s.sid = g.sid
   ) as cgpa
from students s
order by cgpa asc;
```

In fact, I have a suspicion that simply rewriting the query this way will help expose what's wrong with it--it looks to me like maybe the `grades` and `enrollments` tables need another join condition?

Comment: Remove the `,` after `grades g` in your second query.

Comment: What is the purpose of `on e.sid = e.sid` in your `ON` expression?

Answer (score 0):

Two `INNER JOIN`s without `sub-queries` - please try.

```
SELECT s.sid, s.lastname, avg(g.ngrade) cgpa
FROM Students s
JOIN Enrollments e ON s.sid = e.sid
JOIN Grades g ON e.lgrade=g.lgrade
GROUP BY s.sid, s.lastname
ORDER BY 3;
```

Comment: It's `s.sid`, not `s.cid` in your `GROUP BY` statement.